# Define a global variable in laravel and modify it in blades

Tags: php, laravel

I need to define an array and pass it to blade.
But it is important for me to add items to it in some nested blades, then show the result in another blade.

Example:
Blades Tree:
`--plane
----head
----body
------header
------content
------footer`

I want to...

- Send an array like `$var = ['item1', 'item2']` to the blade  "plane".
- Modify it in the blade "header": `$var[] = 'item3'`
- Modify it again in the blade "content": `$var[] = 'item4'`
- Then access it in "footer" like `['item1', 'item2', 'item3, 'item4']`

Comment: all of the in the same page/request ?

Comment: Modifying variables, sent by Controllers, in Blade templates is like going to the store and switching the contents of two different products. You CAN do it, but you really shouldn't. It violates the MVC principle. The view layer, in this case Blade, should only be responsible of receiving immutable input and output it accordingly. If you really need to add items to such variables, you'll most likely want to take a look to View Composers and/or couple it with some custom service object that receives the additions you're talking about.

Comment: @Propaganistas Thanks for clarification.

Comment: You definetely shouldn't be doing this kind of thing in views. Logic goes in Controllers - Middlewares - Models but not in Views

Comment: I think `session` may help you in this case.